The buzzer does not operate properly when restarted by the sw_mode (STM446RET
I am working on a program where pressing switch 2 while music is playing increases the counter value, and if the counter exceeds a certain value, it counts as success. However, if switch 2 is pressed when no music is playing, it counts as a failure. After writing and testing the code, I encountered an issue where the buzzer sound cuts off midway when restarting the program by pressing switch 1 after a success. Could you help me resolve this problem?.
Here is a part of my code that I believe might be causing the issue.
void Timer2_PWM_Init(uint16_t psc, uint16_t arr) {
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;      
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN;      

    GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE15_1;      
    GPIOA->AFR[1] |= 0x1 << GPIO_AFRH_AFSEL15_Pos; 

    TIM2->PSC = psc - 1;        
    TIM2->ARR = arr - 1;       
    TIM2->CCR1 = arr / 2;       
    TIM2->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_1 | TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_2; 
    TIM2->CCER |= TIM_CCER_CC1E; 
    TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;   
}

void Timer2_Stop(void) {
    TIM2->CR1 &= ~TIM_CR1_CEN;
    TIM2->CCR1 = 0;
}

void Play_Tones(void) {
    num_tones = sizeof(tone_psc) / sizeof(tone_psc[0]); 
    for (i = 0; i < num_tones; i++) { 
            state =10;
        Timer2_PWM_Init(tone_psc[i], melody_arr[i]); 
        TimeDelay(melody_delay[random_case%3][i] * 1000); 
        Timer2_Stop();
        if (i != num_tones - 1) { 
            TimeDelay(500000); 
        }
    }
    state =11;
}

void Play_success_Tone(void) {
      LED0_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED0_Pin) << 16;
      LED1_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED1_Pin) << 16;
      LED2_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED2_Pin) << 16;
      LED3_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED3_Pin) << 16;
      LED4_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED4_Pin) << 16;
      LED5_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED5_Pin) << 16;   
      LED6_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED6_Pin) << 16;
      LED7_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED7_Pin) << 16;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Timer2_PWM_Init(tone_psc_success[i], success_tones[i]); 
        TimeDelay(success_delays[i] * 1000); 
        Timer2_Stop(); 
        TimeDelay(200000); 
    }
}


void Play_Fail_Tone(void) {
      LED0_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED0_Pin) << 16;
      LED1_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED1_Pin) << 16;
      LED2_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED2_Pin) << 16;
      LED3_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED3_Pin) << 16;
      LED4_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED4_Pin) << 16;
      LED5_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED5_Pin) << 16;   
      LED6_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED6_Pin) << 16;
      LED7_GPIO_Port->BSRR = (1UL << LED7_Pin) << 16;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        Timer2_PWM_Init(tone_psc_fail[i], fail_tones[i]);
        TimeDelay(fail_delays[i] * 1000); 
        TimeDelay(200000); 
    }
      TimeDelay(500000);
         TimeDelay(500000);
      for (i = 3; i < 4; i++) {
        Timer2_PWM_Init(tone_psc_fail[i], fail_tones[i]);
        TimeDelay(fail_delays[i] * 1000); 
        Timer2_Stop(); 
        TimeDelay(200000); 
    }
      
}
void game_play(void){
   while(num_game>0){
            state =11;
            if (fail_count == 1) {
                  Play_Fail_Tone();
                  break;  //game over
                  }
            else if(f_count >= 80){
                  Play_success_Tone();
                  break;
            }
                  else if (num_game >0) {
                  random_case = rand() % 3;
                  sw_mode = 0; 
                           Play_Tones(); 
                           state =11;
                  random_case = 0;
                  if (fail_count == 1) {
                                 Play_Fail_Tone();
                       break;  //game over
                  }
                  TimeDelay(10000);
            }
                  if (fail_count == 1) {
                                 Play_Fail_Tone();
                       break;  //game over
                  }
            num_game--;
            TimeDelay(1000000);
            TimeDelay(1000000);
            TimeDelay(1000000);
            TimeDelay(1000000);
            TimeDelay(1000000);
   }
 }

void Reset_Game(void) {
    sw_mode = 0;
    fail_count = 0;
    f_count = 0;
    mitter = 80;
    state = 0;
    num_game = 10;
    random_case = 0;
    Timer2_Stop();  // ??? ??
}

int main(void) {
    pb_initialize(); 
    pb_interrupt_init(); 
    led_initialize();

    while (1) {
            if(sw_mode==1 && end_1 == 0){
                      Reset_Game();
               game_play();
               Reset_Game();
            }
    }
}

void EXTI2_IRQHandler(void) {
    if ((EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR2) == EXTI_PR_PR2) { 
        sw_mode = 1; 
        EXTI->PR |= EXTI_PR_PR2; 
    }
}

void EXTI4_IRQHandler(void) {  
  if ((EXTI->PR & EXTI_PR_PR4) == EXTI_PR_PR4) {
    if (state == 10) {
            f_count++;
            mitter -= 1;

            if (f_count % 10 == 0) { 
                rotate_left();
            }
        }
      else if(state ==11){
         fail_count= 1;
                    end_1 =1;
      }
    EXTI->PR |= EXTI_PR_PR4; 
  }
}

I tried modifying the reset condition several times, but the buzzer sound stops working at some poin. so make it so that it doesn't stop working.

Your code is fairly big and not documented. You wrote "Here is a part of my code that I believe might be causing the issue." Can you reproduce the problem with this code? Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Add details about the hardware and compiler you use.

This code is very difficult to review or debug because you have mixed driver and application code. Put anything that accesses hardware in separate files with well-defined interfaces in headers. The application that pulls it all together should not access hardware at all. This way you can test each part separately. You can also test the application on its own by stubbing out the drivers. I suspect that you have a race condition around interrupts accessing all those global variables for which you have not shown the declaration, but separating your interfaces should make it easier to see where.
